# Android open spinner by listview OnItemLongClickListener

Tags: android

I am developing my first android application, but face a difficult problem.
In my application, there is a page that show all sqlite database records by using listview.
I want the spinner can pop up by user long click the listview, but it force close.

```
    private ListView.OnItemLongClickListener modItem = new ListView.OnItemLongClickListener()
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,int index, long arg3)
    {
        //I don't know what should I put in the parameter of the spinner constructor 
        sp_choice = new Spinner(<???>);
        //Same problem that I don't know what should I put in <???>
        ArrayAdapter<String> adt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(<???>,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.choice_array));
        adt.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp_choice.setAdapter(adt);
        return true;
    } 
    };
```

Comment: I guess you need is popup rather than spinner. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think will better to use popup menu or dialog for popup choice instead of making spinner in runtime.

For dialog it looks like this:

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
        AlertDialog.Builder choiceDialogBuilder = new Builder(YourActivity.this);
        choiceDialogBuilder.setSingleChoiceItems(R.array.app_array, 0, new OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, 
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.app_array)[which], 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        dialog.dismiss();
         }
    });
    choiceDialogBuilder.create().show();
    return true;
    } 
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you give me a very useful solution:)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't understand your question...

Let me see if i got this right... You want a dialog with a list of options or registers when long-clicking an item of your listview or are you trying to instantiate a spinner from scratch?

If you want to open a list of options, I would recommend some kind of ListDialog. You can instantiate it adapting the code below:

```
Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getSherlockActivity());
dialog.setTitle(<TITLE>)
            .setItems(<YOUR_LIST>, <Click Listener>)
            .create().show();
```

If not,

You want to create a Spinner from code? Aren't you using a xml resource?
To instantiate a Spinner from code, you must pass the Context on the , as well as the layout params and the mode of the spinner (Dropdown or Dialog), and the string List with your elements on the  of the adapter...
It seems a lot of hard work for a beginner, though... If not necessary, I would recommend you to use a xml resource...

If I didn't get it, please, clarify your question...

Greetings!

Comment: Thank you for your help. Moreover, can I create spinner inside longKickListener dynamically?